# Combine - performing operations on various publisher for elements in array

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, combine

I have my function

```
func synch(cID: Int) -> AnyPublisher<Void, Error> {
        summariesCache
            .lastUpdateTimestamp(cID: cID)
            .prefix(1)
            .flatMap { self.sendRequest(withTimestamp: $0, cID: cID) }
            .map { self.cache.uCache(with: $0.data) }
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
```

which accepts one argument `cID: Int`. I want to refactor it so that this function accepts argument `cID: [Int]`, which is an array, and performs all operations inside on every array's element still returning `AnyPublisher<Void, Error>`, just like the use of DispatchGroup inside for loop for asynchronous operations and completion on end of all.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your methods (`sendRequest`, `uCache` etc) all do things asynchronously, you can get the publisher of the `cID`s, and flat map that to what you currently have.

```
func synch(cIDs: [Int]) -> AnyPublisher<Void, Error> {
    cIDs.publisher.flatMap { cID in
        summariesCache
            .lastUpdateTimestamp(cID: cID)
            .prefix(1)
            .flatMap { self.sendRequest(withTimestamp: $0, cID: cID) }
            .map { self.cache.uCache(with: $0.data) }
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }.eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
```

If you are sending requests to a web server, sending many requests in a short time could cause a heavy load on the server. I would recommend that you send all the cIDs in a single request, if that is possible.

Comment: `.flatMap { self.sendRequest(withTimestamp: $0, cID: cID) }` does not find `cID` argument in scope as we are performing it out of loop and this flatMap's `$0` argument is my timestamp so I can't use it on `cID`

Comment: @Vader20FF Ah I didn't realise both things are used in `sendRequest`. Updated now. This was actually what I first came up with, and I tried to reduce the nesting by just flat mapping to everything until `.prefix(1)`, without realising that you also needed `cID` in `sendRequest`. :)

Comment: do I need to have inner `eraseToAnyPublisher()` at the end of chained functions? I removed it and I have only one `eraseToAnyPublisher()` after outer `.flatMap` and it shows no error.

Comment: @Vader20FF You don't need it indeed, but I left it there hoping that compiler doesn't show a crazy long type in the error messages, or the dreadful "type is ambiguous without more context" error when something wrong happens.

Comment: Ok, thanks :)
Will check if this solution really works in my implementation :)